# Create key-value pair from csv php

Tags: php, arrays, csv, object, key

I have a csv file like below

```
tl_blade_thickness,tl_blade
test1,test1
test2,test2
test3,test3
test4,test4
test5,test5
test6,test6
test7,test7
test8,test8
test9,test9
```

I'm trying to create a key value pair array like below.

```
["tl_blade_thickness"=>["test1","test2","test3",...],tl_blade=>["test1","test2","test3",...]]
```

I tried like this below.

```
$content = fopen("csv.csv", "r");
 $all_rows = array();
 $header = fgetcsv($content);
 while ($row = fgetcsv($content)) {
       $all_rows[] = array_combine($header, $row);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the first line of the file to create the keys of the array. Then push each field of the remaining lines into the corresponding element keys.

```
$content = fopen("csv.csv", "r");
$headers = fgetcsv($content);
$all_rows = array_fill_keys($headers, []);
while ($row = fgetcsv($content)) {
    foreach ($headers as $i => $name) {
        $all_rows[$name][] = $row[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI you don't need the `array_fill_keys` as they will be created.

Comment: @AbraCadaver True, but it feels cleaner to initialize everything.